# How do I remove the small gaps in a foreign alphabet font on Linux?

Tags: debian, fonts

Since it is notoriously stable, I use Debian for work (I'm a mathematician). Now, I've found a very nice font for the predominant script of India (which is Devanagari), and it's called "Sanskrit2003". The official download site is here:

https://omkarananda-ashram.org/Sanskrit/itranslator2003.htm#dls

Now, unfortunately, on Linux the letters aren't joined up correctly. Furthermore, this issue seems to be font-specific, since I had the same issue with the Arabic font I was using, until I found a better font (called "Amiri") which does not display this degeneracy.

Now my question is: How do I make the letters join up, so that the upper line that is ubiquitous in Devanagari becomes a single solid stroke, without the tiny interruptions that must bother every aesthetically-minded reader?

Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT: I've now tried to move the characters closer together using FontForge, but so far, this has only yielded good results in Firefox, whereas there are artifacts when compiling a TeX file using TeXstudio. I fear that I will have to edit each character separately. This would be a lot of work.

EDIT2: The font also has gaps on Windows 11.

EDIT3: Since the process of correcting the font by hand seemed to tedious, I have conducted a slightly more creative internet search and found a font that gets it right: https://ektype.in/font-family/baloo2.html

I'm now using this one; it's FOSS as well, and its only drawback is that it does not have serifs. It should be noted that the Chandas font also doesn't display any artifacts, but it uses the old style sophisticated ligatures, which are not standard anymore.

Comment: In a word processor or page-layout program, I might try setting the letterspacing to just barely condensed, enough to close the gaps. For anything where you don't have the ability to control the letterspacing, you'd need to either replace the font or modify it using a tool like FontForge.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I was afraid it might be so. I tried FontForge, but have been unsuccessful so far. But since there are only finitely many features of that program, I expect to be successful after further attempts.

Comment: Which version of Debian are you using -- and which programs, specifically?

Comment: @user1686 I'm running bullseye, and the depiction is the same across all programmes, especially Mozilla Firefox and TeXstudio.

Comment: I was thinking that the issue might not be exclusively because of the font, but potentially also because of the _shaping engine_ library (many Linux programs use HarfBuzz, I'll check whether it looks the same with the latest version 3.0). And some of the components involved even have font-specific workarounds embedded...

Comment: @user1686 While that might be true, I just found that Windows 11 displays it incorrectly too.

Comment: Notably, even a screenshot from the organisation itself shows that the characters are placed wrongly: https://omkarananda-ashram.org/Sanskrit/main_window.jpg